# Noise power spectral density and $|X(\omega)|^2$. Why are those quantities associated usually ? Their definitions are different

Tags: power, signal-processing, noise

I consider a generic signal $X(t)$. We could imagine to fix ideas $X(t)=\sqrt{R}I(t)$ ($R$ being a resistor and $I$ current flowing through it)

The energy of this signal is defined as $E=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |X(t)|^2 dt$. The motivation of calling this "signal energy" can be seen from my signal example (it would give the heat dissipated in the resistor).

From Parseval theorem, we have: $\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |X(t)|^2 dt=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty} |X(\omega)|^2 d \omega$.

From this, we can define the energy spectral density $E_{xx}(\omega)=|X(\omega)|^2$

Unfortunately, for many signal (if they are not square integrable for instance), $X(\omega)$ does not exists. This is the reason why in signal processing people introduced the power spectral density as being:

$$S_{xx}(\omega)=\lim_{T \to +\infty} \mathbb{E}[|X_T(\omega)|^2]$$

Where $X_T(\omega)$ is a windowed Fourier transform:

$$X_T(\omega)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{T}}\int_{-T/2}^{+T/2}dt X(t) e^{-i\omega t} $$

Then, what people call the noise power spectral density does not exactly match what we would like initially (it would be easier to work with $|X(\omega)|^2$), but this new definition works for many more signals. Furthermore there are some very usefull theorem on this quantity like the Wiener–Khinchin theorem.

### **My question:**

I am okay to create a new definition for noise power if it makes math doable and provides good theorem. My troubles start when I try to put physics label on it.

In theoretical derivations, when it exists, we usually have access to $\mathbb{E}(|X(\omega)|^2)$. For example,
I take the important example for my purpose which is the Johnson-Nyquist noise. In this case, we have ($V$ being the voltage around a resistor at thermal equilibrium at temperature $T$):

$$\mathbb{E}(|V(\omega)|^2)=4 R k_b T$$

And we call this quantity the power spectral density. It can be seen on [the wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson%E2%80%93Nyquist_noise), or on page 70 [here](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4729). However it is **not** the power spectral density (it doesn't come from a windowed calculation). But anyway we usually do "as if" it was the case and then we use all the results from signal processing to derive some relations. Also in [this document](https://arxiv.org/abs/0810.4729) (I could find other), we use this assimilation $S_{xx}(\omega) \leftrightarrow \mathbb{E}(|X(\omega)|^2)$ to derive some properties.

Why are people doing this ? Is it kind of an "handwaving" things that wouldn't be too far from reality so that we can assimilate when the quantity exist $S_{xx}(\omega)$.

In summary: why when $\mathbb{E}(|X(\omega)|^2)$ does exist, physisict associate it to the noise power spectral density even if the two quantities do not have the same definition ? I would like to have a source explaining it if possible.

Comment: I always thouight that some sort of windowed quantity was the more physical, because, when we measure the noise, we only connect our measuring apparatus for a finite time.

Comment: @mikestone thank you for your comment. I would probably agree with you on this (but my question is different from this point). Thanks.

Comment: maybe if you changed the notation it would not be so confusing, $X(t)$ vs. $X(\omega)$ or $T(ime)$ vs.$T(emperature)$

Comment: @hyportnex I'm not sure to see where it is confusing ? I added a precision just before the $k_b T$ to say that this $T$ is temperature if it makes things more clear. But for the rest I think the notation are pretty clear ?

Comment: My answer on Signal Processing Stack Exchange may be helpful: https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/65992/27128

Comment: @jgerber indeed it is very close. You make my point more clear: the two quantities are definitely not the same thing even though they are called the same often in litterature. Then I would like to ask: is there an easy relationship between those quantities ? Let's say that for my signal $\mathbb{E}[|X(\omega)|^2]$ is well defined, can I relate it easily to $S_{xx}(\omega)$ or not really ?

Comment: It's a bit tricky. I would have to think about it more, but I suggest you try to think about it for the following signals: white noise, pure tone (like $e^{i \omega t}$), and a finite (amplitude and time) box pulse. 

I think the important thing to realize is that $E\left[|X(\omega)|^2\right]$ will only be well-defined if you signal has finite energy and this only occurs if it is transient in time. If this is the case then you will find $S_{xx}(\omega)$ is always zero (because the $\frac{1}{T}$ gets smaller but the windowed numerator is fixed).

Comment: So the conclusion is that these two measures of the signal spectrum are relevant for different kinds of signals.. I know this isn't 100% satisfying and leaves more work for you to do which is why I put it as a comment instead of an answer..

Comment: @jgerber Allright, thanks. Actually I think you mainly answered my question with your other post. Indeed it is an abusive language to associate noise power spectral density to the quantity $|X(\omega)|^2$. The real definition is the one I gave in my question. Then, I guess in practice for theoretical calculation people usually start with the fact it is the F.T of the autocorrelation function. The "real definition" has a nice interpretation but is "in general" not easy to calculate with.